# pyodbc [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'PostgreSQL Unicode' : file not found

Tags: python, database, postgresql, pyodbc

I'm trying to use pyodbc to connect postgresql db:

```
import pyodbc
conn_str = (
    "DRIVER={PostgreSQL Unicode};"
    "DATABASE=postgres;"
    "UID=postgres;"
    "PWD=11111;"
    "SERVER=localhost;"
    "PORT=5432;"
    )
conn = pyodbc.connect(conn_str)
```

Error:

```
Error: ('01000', "[01000] [unixODBC][Driver Manager]Can't open lib 'PostgreSQL Unicode' : file not found (0) (SQLDriverConnect)")
```

Did I missed install some other packages like driver ?

Comment: Have you installed psqlodbc? If so, how have you done it? You can get windows installer/src from here: https://ftp.postgresql.org/pub/odbc/versions/README